# How to change closing lid behavior on AC and batter on Elementary Juno

Tags: release-juno, suspend, laptop

I want to change lid closing behavior on Juno to:

- When power is connected and the laptop lid is closed, a screen lock or nothing.
- With the power off (on battery) and closing the laptop lid - suspend.

Currently there's no option to change that so any lid close suspends the laptop irregardless of being on battery or AC.

I tried changing dconf of the corresponding features with dconf editor but Elementary does not respect those changes. Any idea how to achieve those actions in Juno?.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use system settings? Let's try to achieve this way,

- Please go to the "System Settings" and click "Power".
- After that please click "Unlock" and enter your password to unlock some settings.
- Now please change *lid behavior however you want for battery or plugged in.

Hopefully this will work. I will look forward to your reply.

Comment: On all the GUI of Elementary OS there is no option for "lid behavior" in power setting even with unlocking advanced options.  That's why i asked the question in the first

Comment: You are using a laptop, right? Here's how [my power settings look like](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-power/raw/master/data/screenshot.png?raw=true).

Comment: The setting in the screenshot changes behavior of lid closing irregardless on whether the laptop is on AC or battery. My question was how to have separate options on lid close; suspend on battery and no suspend on AC power.

Comment: Yes, there are separate options available in the settings as shown in my earlier comment. Can you please post a screenshot of your power settings?

Comment: The separate settings for AC/Battery are for suspend on inactivity timer. Not for closing the lid; closing lid has one setting with no customization based on AC/Battery status